# Apple store and application bundle

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm not sure whether it's possible or even making sense so I'm asking here. If I have a third-party C++ source. Can I compile it into an iPhone binary? The binary would then be packed in my application bundle which then submitted to AppleStore. The application bundle contain my app, just that it also contains a copy of the third-party binary.

The point is that I'm imagining if this is possible, I could use the third-party binary via command and hence avoid static linking.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS applications that aren't run on jailbroken devices don't have any privileges to execute other programs. You'd be better off static linking.

Comment: Is that because they can't make a new process?

Comment: More or less, yeah. You're not allowed to `fork()`, `exec()`, or anything else which might allow you to execute malicious code or break out of the sandbox. Obviously, jailbreakers continue to find ways to do so, but typically with the cooperation of the user.

Comment: Actually, developers are allowed to run code from other languages within their app. See my answer below. Basically, as long as the code is all included in the app, apple doesn't have a problem with it.

Comment: "Within their app" sounds like "compiled into the same binary." The OP is asking about distributing a separate executable as part of their application bundle (i.e., there would be two executables in the bundle).

Comment: Justin is right. My research shows me there is no way to run the second binary in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Apps are allowed to run code from other languages as long as all the code they run is included with the application. For example, you couldn't write an app that allows the user to write Java programs, but you could include a little Java compiler as long as it was compiling code written and uploaded with the app. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. Does that mean I have to do static linking?

Comment: Apple would approve your app with the third-party binary as part of it. My friend works at Apple and we had a lengthy discussion about the specifics of this.